# Navigator share not work in converting the web site into APK

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, apk

```js
$(".shared").click(function() {
 
    if (navigator.share !== undefined) {
    navigator.share({
      title: '<? echo $title_share; ?>',
      url  : '<? echo $url_share; ?>'
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Shared successfully'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('An error has occurred'));
  } else {
    console.log('Your browser doesn\'t support Web Share API');
  }
      
 });
```

navigator share does not work in converting the website into APK with appsgeyser or gonative.io

can not make web APIs work from the conversion, so it gives me as if the browser does not support it. In the Android mobile browser, it works perfectly. is there a way to create a share button in native Java and integrate it into HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your website runs in a different browser check the user agent, for debugging.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share -> see here for compatabilatie
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp -> JavaScript check user agent

Answer (score 0):

gives me this result with  gonative.io

User-agent header sent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G900F Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36 GoNativeAndroid/1.0 gonative

gives me this result with appsgeyser

User-agent header sent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-ie; GT-P1000 Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

in theory it should not work with gonative.io?